# How do SimpleRoundTo works

Tags: delphi, floating-point, delphi-2007

Why does this expression evaluate true?

```
SimpleRoundTo(93.599, -2) > 93.6
```

When I use the `SimpleRoundTo` like this

```
ShowMessage(FloatToStr(SimpleRoundTo(93.599, -2)));
```

it shows `93.6`.

Comment: This issue boils down to `93.6` not being exactly representable in a binary floating point type. And your `SimpleRoundTo` (presumably from an older Delphi) is failing to return the closest representable value to `93.6`. Anyway, the bottom line is that you have unrealistic expectations. You need to absorb this issue of representability.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i'm using like this now; 
if SimpleRoundTo(93.599, -2) > SimpleRoundTo(93.6, -2) then
and this code returns False. Do you think that new line has problem?

Comment: You need to step back and address the issue of representability. Are you aware that `93.6` is not representable? Do you understand what that means. Check here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=93.6 and see that to double precision, the closest representable value is in fact `93.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375`. You aren't going to make progress by trying different bits of code. What you need is understanding. Take some time. Read the answers at the dupe. Follow the links. Make sure you understand what is meant by representability.

Comment: If we are going to talk about `SimpleRoundTo` though, we need to know which version of Delphi you use. Recent versions use a different implementation of `SimpleRoundTo`. I believe you are using an older version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, i'm going to read about the problem by using links. I'm using Delphi 2007.

Comment: This is a really good link: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html  Start here!